# Visualize a Neo4J Path and embed in a web application

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-visualization

I am using Neo4J and py2neo driver for my web application. I have shortest path queries and I want to visualize like this,

[image: shortest path between two nodes visualization]

1. The graph highlights the nodes and relationships in the path
2. Every node and relationship is interactive - hover over to get more details

Is there any visualization tool which takes a Neo4j path and return an interactive element like this? I want to embed this in my application and update when user changes the query.

Already looked at http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-visualization/